# Id is not associated after seeding with nested attributes on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, seed

How come the `space_listing_id` is empty after I seed?

I have this on my model.

```
 class SpaceListing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

 validates :title, presence: true
 validates :description, presence: true
 validates :day_rent, presence: true
 validates :monthly_rent, presence: true
 validates :space_type, presence: true
 validates :environment_type, presence: true
 validates :size_length, presence: true
 validates :size_width, presence: true
 validates :size_height, presence: true
end
```

This is what my `seed.rb` has:

```
SpaceListing.create!([
  {
user_id: 1,
title: "Hipster Vest",
description: "Hipster's favorite spot",
street_number: "10",
route: "Hipster Street",
city: "San Francisco",
state: "CA",
zip_code: "94108",
country: "United States",
space_type: "Garage",
environment_type: "Outdoor",
monthly_rent: 100,
day_rent: 3,
size_width: 10,
size_height: 10,
size_length: 10,
latitude: 37.7875474,
longitude: -122.4049517,
images_attributes: [
   {image_url: "https://media.giphy.com/media/26BRwxtVBt8dWEuGs/giphy.gif",
    space_listing_id: },
   {image_url: "https://media.giphy.com/media/l3UcgEIw80eyb36kU/giphy.gif"}
  ]
 }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accepts_nested_attributes` creates a new attribute that can be passed into ActiveRecord methods, such as .create and .update. In your case, that attribute will be called `:images_attributes`.

The following code will solve your problem.

```
SpaceListing.create!([
  {
    user_id: 1,
    title: "Hipster Vest",
    description: "Hipster's favorite spot",
    street_number: "10",
    route: "Hipster Street",
    city: "San Francisco",
    state: "CA",
    zip_code: "94108",
    country: "United States",
    space_type: "Garage",
    environment_type: "Outdoor",
    monthly_rent: 100,
    day_rent: 3,
    size_width: 10,
    size_height: 10,
    size_length: 10,
    latitude: 37.7875474,
    longitude: -122.4049517,
    images_attributes: [
      { image_url:  "https://media.giphy.com/media/26BRwxtVBt8dWEuGs/giphy.gif"},
      { image_url:  "https://media.giphy.com/media/l3UcgEIw80eyb36kU/giphy.gif"}
    ]
  }
])
```

UPDATE:
You seem to have updated the question. I'll answer it. You do not need to include `:space_listing_id` in the attribute hashes. Using the code I posted above, Rails will automatically associate the records and populate the `:space_listing_id` key.